# Redis for non unique keys

Tags: redis

Can anyone suggest a way we can store the data in Redis Cache where the keys are not unique.

For an instance, I have a database with two columns A and B. A is always unique and hence we can create a Redis hash using it.
However, B is not unique and for B there can be multiple data of column A.

Can someone suggest a way we can create a Redis Hash that supports non unique Keys.

Comment: The philosophy of Redis mandates that you think about how you wish/need to access the data, and choose the best-fitting data structure accordingly. How do you plan to "query" the 'B' values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **impossible** to create non unique keys in redis hash.My suggestion is to append the values of column B in single hash key.

For example,if column B contains the following value.,

```
B | value
key_1 | value1
key_2 | value2
key_3 | value3
key_1 | value4
key_2 | value5
```

you can store the value in redis hash by appending the `value1` and `value4` in `key_1`,like this.,

```
key_1 = value1:value4
key_2 = value2:value5
key_3 = value3
```

P.S: For implementing this method, you need to make two round trips to the redis-server for getting the value already present in the redis and then back setting the new value in redis.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the values on B column(which are not unique), you can use **Redis list**

See [Redis data types](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#lists)